# How can I combine tables and create a new record (when missing) from a previous table?

Tags: sql-server, hiveql

I get provided a list of users and their home zip code every month.  However, not every user provides a zip code for every month so my monthly tables are never the same size.

What I want to do is create one master table that has a record for every month for every user starting with the first month.  Then if a user in the first month doesn't appear in the second month they should still get a record for the second month with the zip code assigned based on the prior month.

For example, I have two tables that look like this:

```
UserNumber Month  ZIP
1          201701 12345
2          201701 30032
3          201701 01432
Etc.
```

```
UserNumber Month  ZIP
1          201702 12345
3          201702 01433
4          201702 30032
Etc.
```

You can see that some ZIP codes will change (user 3 "moved") which is ok.  But user 2 doesn't have a record for 201702.  But my new master table should have a record for them where the ZIP code from 201701 is used.  So the master table should look like this:

```
UserNumber Month  ZIP
1          201701 12345
1          201702 12345
2          201701 30032
2          201702 30032 
3          201701 01432
Etc.
```

As mentioned, there is a record for user 2 for 201702 using the same zip code where we had a record.  Sometimes there will be multiple missing months so I want to grab the most recent record that is less than the current month.

I have tried creating multiple temporary tables based on the table intersects and then appending them together and that worked.  But with 30+ months of data that was going to get very complicated and tedious so I'm hoping there is a better way.  And this master table would have to be updated each month as well.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Currently the data is in S3 which I access using Hive so a HiveQL solution would be ideal so I don't have to import all this data into SSMS but if it's easier to do this in SSMS using SQL I can make that work as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at `UNION` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Sounds like you need a date table to find the missing months for each User to insert the row into the Master. If I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: It is not clear what is the second table for and how it corellates with this requirement: "create one master table that has a record for every month for every user starting with the first month" Do you want to merge data from two tables and it should be records for all months? What is the range of months required? Please edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this sounds like it would work, at least once you get the initial set built. This does make the assumption that the process is updated every month so that there can't be gaps in the series:

```
insert into Master (userid, month, zip)
select
    coalesce(u.userid, m.userid),
    coalesce(u.month, convert(char(6), dateadd(month, 1, m.month + '01'), 112),
    coalesce(u.zip, m.zip)
from ZipUpdate u full outer join Master m
    on m.userid = u.userid and m.month =
        convert(char(6), dateadd(month, -1, u.month + '01'), 112);
```

If you want to fill in the gaps you could start with an empty table and just run this 30+ times in a loop. If the table names are predictable then something like this could generate the entire script.

```
declare @sql varchar(8000);
declare @dt date = '20170101';
while @dt < cast('20190901' as date)
begin
    set @sql = 'insert into Master (userid, month, zip)
    select
        coalesce(u.userid, m.userid),
        ''' + convert(char(6), @dt, 112) + ''',
        coalesce(u.zip, m.zip)
    from '
        /* change this expression as needed */
        + 'ZipUpdate'
        + convert(varchar(3), datediff(month, '20170101', @dt) + 1)
        + ' u full outer join Master m
        on m.userid = u.userid and m.month = ''' +
        + convert(char(6), dateadd(month, -1, @dt), 112) + '''
    where u.month = ''' + convert(char(6), @dt, 112) + ''';'

    set @dt = dateadd(month, 1, @dt);
    select @sql;
end
```

Comment: thank you so much!  I'm implementing the first code you suggested and it appears to be working the way I want!  The coalesce function is not something I thought of but that is a really good solution.  I can then save this and update each month as needed.

Comment: Update: after doing some testing I noticed that when you add file 3+ it starts to duplicate records when they shouldn't be.  So I ended up with multiple records for some users.  I fixed this by added "Where m.month = 201702" (or whatever is the month prior to the one I'm adding.  That appears to be working now!

Comment: @NFlint The join was supposed to be matching up the months that way. It's certainly possible I got that wrong since I couldn't really test it out. Did you possibly leave that out by accident?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is suitable for your question:

```
begin tran

create table #tbl1 (UserNumber int, [Month] int, ZIP char(5));
create table #tbl2 (UserNumber int, [Month] int, ZIP char(5));
create table #tbl3 (UserNumber int, [Month] int, ZIP char(5));

insert into #tbl1 (UserNumber, [Month], ZIP)
select 1, 201701, '12345' union all
select 2, 201701, '30032' union all
select 3, 201701, '01432';

insert into #tbl2 (UserNumber, [Month], ZIP)
select 1, 201702, '12345' union all
select 3, 201702, '01433' union all
select 4, 201702, '30032';

insert into #tbl3 (UserNumber, [Month], ZIP)
select 3, 201703, '01435' union all
select 4, 201703, '30032';

create table #full (UserNumber int, [Month] int, ZIP char(5));

insert into #full (UserNumber, [Month], ZIP)
select UserNumber, [Month], ZIP from #tbl1
union all
select UserNumber, [Month], ZIP from #tbl2
union all
select UserNumber, [Month], ZIP from #tbl3;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_Full] ON #full (UserNumber asc, [Month] asc);

create table #month ([Month] int);

insert into #month ([Month])
select [Month]
from #full
group by [Month];

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_Month] ON #month ([Month] asc);

create table #start_usernumber (UserNumber int, [Month] int);

insert into #start_usernumber (UserNumber, [Month])
select UserNumber, min([Month])
from #full
group by UserNumber;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_StartUserNumber] ON #start_usernumber (UserNumber asc, [Month] asc);

select su.UserNumber,
       m.[Month],
       case when(f.ZIP is null) then (select top(1) f0.ZIP from #full as f0 where f0.UserNumber=su.UserNumber and f0.[Month]<m.[Month] and f0.ZIP is not null order by f0.[Month] desc) else f.ZIP end as ZIP
from #start_usernumber as su
inner join #month as m on su.[Month]<=m.[Month]
left join #full as f on m.[Month]=f.[Month] and su.UserNumber=f.UserNumber
order by su.UserNumber, m.[Month];

rollback tran
```

**Result:**

[image]